# Linq extension. Change property value in source list

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I made this extension, I have to modify the value of a property on the source list. The problem I have is that it does not change the value in the source list, the value of the item is changed well.

this is my extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SetIndex<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> propertyExpression)
{
    MemberExpression body = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (body == null)
    {
        return source;
    }

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = body.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propertyInfo == null || propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(int))
    {
        return source;
    }

    string propertyName = body.Member.Name;
    int index = 0;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(item, index++, null);
    }

    return source;
}
```

this is my code to test:

```
public class Persona
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public class PersonaGroup
{
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }
}


IList<Persona> listPersonas = new List<Persona>()
{
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Lopez", Name = "Tilo" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Dominguez", Name = "Raul" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Martinez", Name = "Manuel" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Martinez", Name = "Rogelio" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Lopez", Name = "Roberto" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Martinez", Name = "Alen" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Lopez", Name = "Mario" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Dominguez", Name = "Duran" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Martinez", Name = "Maria" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Dominguez", Name = "Marta" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Lopez", Name = "Pedro" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Dominguez", Name = "Martin" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Dominguez", Name = "Diego" },
    new Persona{ Lastname = "Lopez", Name = "El" }
};

IList<PersonaGroup> listPersonasGroups = listPersonas
                                .GroupBy(p => p.Lastname)
                                .Select(pg => new PersonaGroup { Lastname = pg.Key, Count = pg.Count() })
                                .SetIndex(pg => pg.Index)
                                .ToList();

foreach (PersonaGroup personaGroup in listPersonasGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} : {2}", 
                personaGroup.Index, 
                personaGroup.Count, 
                personaGroup.Lastname);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

result:

```
0 - 5 : Lopez
0 - 5 : Dominguez
0 - 4 : Martinez
```

While I wrote my question, I detected taht the problem is when use `Select`, but I do not know how to fix it or why it is that I can not modify the list.
I know I can use `yield return item;` in a `foreach` but I would be more useful to change "source".

thanks.

Comment: By the way, do you know about Select with index in linq: `collection.Select((item, index) => result);`. I think it is similar to your `SetIndex` extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with standard LINQ methods:

```
IList<PersonaGroup> listPersonasGroups = listPersonas
                                .GroupBy(p => p.Lastname)
                                .Select((pg, i) => new PersonaGroup {
                                                        Lastname = pg.Key,
                                                        Count = pg.Count(),
                                                        Index = i
                                })
                                .ToList();
```

`Select` overload with `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` parameter works like your custom extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (selector == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("selector");
    }
    return Enumerable.SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
}

private static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector)
{
    int num = -1;
    checked
    {
        foreach (TSource current in source)
        {
            num++;
            yield return selector(current, num);
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this piece of code:

```
foreach (TSource item in source)
{
    propertyInfo.SetValue(item, index++, null);
}
return source;
```

`source` is deferred IEnumerable, which you enumerate twice. In `return source;` there are no changes at all. For instance you can change it to:

```
var array = source.ToArray();
foreach (TSource item in array)
{
    propertyInfo.SetValue(item, index++, null);
}
return array;
```

Comment: +1 because it solves the problem in my extension, but I choose the solution of @MarcinJuraszek because it solves my business problem